# Remove validation with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails form with nested attributes. User can update its `caddy` with 2 ways:

- By writing its delivering address into nested attributes of a model `Address`,
- or by selecting a checkbox meaning "I don't want to be delivered"

It's generating a set of params like this :

```
{
  "id"=>"mine",
  "caddy"=> {
    "address_attributes"=>{"street"=>"", "city"=>"" [...]},
    "use_address"=>"1"
  }
}
```

Some parts of my models:

```
Model Caddy < AR::Base
  belongs_to :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
  attr_accessor :use_address
end

Model Address < AR::Base
  validates :street, :presence => true
end
```

The issue is that when user check `use_address` checkbox, the `address_attributes` should not be used, but they are, and raise a validation error from the `street` presence.

I tried to add this method into `Caddy` to override `use_addresss=` generated by `attr_accessor`:

```
def use_address=(v)
  if v == '1'
    self.address_id = nil
    self.address_attributes = {}
    self.address = nil
  end
  super
end
```

But it changes nothing (`address_attributes` should be `nil` then be the hash params).

The only solution I found is to change params directly into my controller, but it's crappy. Do you have any other solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do this with overriding `assign_attributes`:

```
def assign_attributes(attrs)
  unless ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean(attrs.delete(:use_address))
    self.address && self.address.mark_for_destruction
    # or self.address_id = nil if you don't want to destroy existing address
    attrs.delete(:address_attributes)
  end
  super(attrs)    
end
```